# Programmatically Setting Emacs Window as Input Focus

Tags: emacs, window, focus, elisp, gud

How do I programmaticaly force my Emacs X Window to get current user input focus?

I want to use this in the following Bash script

```
# Debug in Emacs using GDB
function emacs-gdb()
{
    if [ -z $1 ]; then
        echo -e "Usage: $FUNCNAME EXE EXE_ARGS...";
    else
        if (($# >= 2)); then
            local ARGS="--args ${@:1:100}";
        else
            local ARGS="$1";
        fi
    emacsclient --eval "(gdb \"gdb -i=mi $ARGS\")"
    fi
}
```

to make the Emacs window automatically get window focus.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding the call to `raise-frame` in your eval code.

For example:

```
emacsclient --eval "(progn (raise-frame) (gdb \"gdb -i=mi $ARGS\"))"
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work on gnome-shell. Neither when the frame is visible nor iconized.

Comment: I was thinking you want to create a new Emacs frame with `gdb` called. If that's the case you can add the `-c` argument to the `emacsclient` call. Otherwise, to focus an existing Emacs frame, you have to use the external program `wmctrl` like @abo-abo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this copied from somewhere related to `org-protocol`.
It should help you as well:

```lisp
(defadvice raise-frame (after make-it-work (&optional frame) activate)
    "Work around some bug? in raise-frame/Emacs/GTK/Metacity/something.
     Katsumi Yamaoka posted this in
     http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel:39702"
     (call-process
     "wmctrl" nil nil nil "-s" "1")
     (call-process
     "wmctrl" nil nil nil "-i" "-R"
     (frame-parameter (or frame (selected-frame)) 'outer-window-id)))
```

This is in addition to @tungd's advice of calling `raise-frame` of course.